# What field type should I use for currency?

Tags: fields

Can someone explain in (easy English) the difference between Number and Integer/Decimal? I understand Integer and Decimal... What is the point of Number? Should I use Number for product prices?

Comment: Hi.  To get an answer to this question it would help if you could be a bit more descriptive both of what you are trying to do, and about the version of EE you are using (and whether you are using add-ons etc.).  Thanks!

Comment: I am creating a new field type Text Input for a product price. There are three options, Number, Integer and Decimal. I am unsure to use Number or Decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the field **Text Field** the four types of **Allowed content** (i.e. what you are allowed to put into the field if EE will let you save the entry it is part of) are:

- **All** - any content (text or numbers) is OK
- **Number** - content entered must as a number (i.e. numerals only - integer or decimals are OK)
- **Integer** - content entered must be an integer (i.e. numerals only, no decimal point)
- **Decimal** - content entered must be a decimal number (i.e. including a decimal point) - words entered are rejected, integers entered are converted to decimals

HTH